# Ways to speed up array operations in JS without third part libraries?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, optimization, artificial-intelligence

For a Computer Science class, I created a connect 4 AI in JavaScript that is based off of Keith Galli's connect 4 AI in python. Compared to his, my heuristic function runs much slower even with optimizations (7-11 ms vs. <1 ms). The only real difference between my code and his is that he uses the numpy library for multidimensional array operations. I have heard of NumJS, but the problem is, since I'm in the code.org AppLab workspace, I am unable to import/install and third-party libraries.

For reference, here is my heuristic function that evaluates the positional advantage:

```
function score_position(board, piece){
  var start = Date.now();
  
  if (!score_position.cache) {
    score_position.cache = {};
  }

  var key = board.join("") + piece;

  if (score_position.cache.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var end = Date.now();
    console.log("Elapsed time (cached): " + (end - start) + "ms");
    return score_position.cache[key];
  }
  
  var score = 0;
  var center_count = 0;
  for(var i=0; i < board.length; i++){
    if (board[i][3] === piece) {
      center_count++;
    }
  }
  score += center_count * 3;

  var col_array = [];
  var diag1_array = [];
  var diag2_array = [];

  for(var r=0; r<ROW_COUNT; r++){
    for(var c=0; c<COLUMN_COUNT-3; c++){
      var win = board[r].slice(c, c+WINDOW_LENGTH);
      if (win.indexOf('') === -1) {
        score += evaluate_window(win, piece);
      }
    }
  }
  
  for(var r=0; r<ROW_COUNT; r++){
    for(var c=0; c<COLUMN_COUNT; c++){
      col_array[c] = board[r][c];
    }
    for(var ct=0; ct<ROW_COUNT-3; ct++){
      var win = col_array.slice(ct, ct+WINDOW_LENGTH);
      if (win.indexOf('') === -1) {
        score += evaluate_window(win, piece);
      }
    }
  }
  
  for(var r=0; r<ROW_COUNT-3; r++){
    for(var c=0; c<COLUMN_COUNT-3; c++){
      diag1_array[0] = board[r][c];
      diag1_array[1] = board[r+1][c+1];
      diag1_array[2] = board[r+2][c+2];
      diag1_array[3] = board[r+3][c+3];
      if(diag1_array.indexOf('') === -1) {
        score += evaluate_window(diag1_array, piece);
      }
    }
  }
  
  for(var r=0; r<ROW_COUNT-3; r++){
    for(var c=0; c<COLUMN_COUNT-3; c++){
      diag2_array[0] = board[r+3][c];
      diag2_array[1] = board[r+2][c+1];
      diag2_array[2] = board[r+1][c+2];
      diag2_array[3] = board[r][c+3];
      if(diag2_array.indexOf('') === -1) {
        score += evaluate_window(diag2_array, piece);
      }
    }
  }

  
  score_position.cache[key] = score;
  
  var end = Date.now();
  console.log("Elapsed time:" + (end-start) + "ms");
  
  return score;
  
}
```

This function just looks through the rows, columns, and diagonals of the given board and scores the windows in them using another function called evaluate windows:

```
function evaluate_window(win, piece){
  
  if(!evaluate_window.cache){
    evaluate_window.cache = {};
  }
  
  var key = win.join("") + piece;
  
  if (evaluate_window.cache.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return evaluate_window.cache[key];
  }
  
    var score = 0;
    var opp_piece = 1;
    if(piece == 1){
        opp_piece = 2;
    }

    if(win.count(piece) == 4){
        score += 100;
    } else if (win.count(piece) == 3 && win.count(0) == 1){
        score += 5;
    } else if (win.count(piece) == 2 && win.count(0) == 2){
        score += 2;
    }
    if (win.count(opp_piece) == 3 && win.count(0) == 1){
        score -= 4;
    }
    
    evaluate_window.cache[key] = score;

    return score;
}
```

In both functions, I use memoization caching in order to reduce the speeds of repeat board/window states. Also, I skip certain for loops if the window that I'm evaluating is empty. Even with these optimizations, the code still runs slow, so I think it might just be the computationally expensive array operations. What is the best way to make this code run faster?

Comment: This question is more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Marc, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You could have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *is for* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.